# How to get a backup of files at specific interval of time?

Tags: php, timer, backup

I have created a web application storing files online. I want to get a backup of those uploaded files on a regular basis, meaning after a day or an hour. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [cron](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html) if you're on linux or [task scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) if you're on windows to schedule a periodic script.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a rsync command to run every hour or day or whenever using cron. Rsync does a byte for byte copy of a directory or file.

```
rsync -av --delete /source/folder /destination/folder
```

save this as backup.sh 
then on a terminal or ssh session on your server type this:

```
#crontab -e 
5 0 * * * /path/to/backup.sh
```

This will call your backup script 5 minutes past midnight every night.

Comment: Its pretty easy. Im assuming your on a linux server.
First look up options for the rsync command, as it can do some amazing things even copy to remote hard drives. Your command would look like this:

rsync -av --delete /source/folder /destination/folder
save this as backup.sh
then on a terminal or ssh session on your server type this:
crontab -e
5 0 * * * /path/to/backup.sh